# Insert spherical image inside 3D scene in PDF using Latex media9

Tags: graphics, pdftex, 3d, media9, wide-image

I have successfully added a 3D scene + 3D object in PDF using Latex. I want to know if there is a way to add a spherical/equirectangular/panoramic image in the background of the 3D scene. If there isn't a way to do this, I believe, a sphere with a texture map can be inserted into the 3D scene that spans it's background.  If someone can guide me on the latter technique, that would also help. The code I currently have is give below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{lmodern}      
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\linespread{1.05}         

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}    
\usepackage[MeX]{polski}     

\usepackage{graphicx}                  
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includemedia[
    width=15cm,
    height=15cm,
    activate=pageopen,
    3Dmenu,
    3Dc2c=4 2 3,
    3Dcoo=4.413303375244141 2.195653200149536 -0.000011444091796875,
    3Droo=429.49035778293376,
    3Dlights=Headlamp,
    3Dbg=0.5 0.5 0.5,
    activate=pageopen,
    ]{}{sphere_simple (2).u3d}
    \caption{3D Viewer}
\label{Fig:pinlock}
\end{figure}\par

\end{document}
```

I'm new to the media9 and Latex packages, any help in this regard will be appreciated.